# Mac System Status Bar Focus

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I've added a menu to my systemStatusBar by this code:

```
statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
```

And then set its properties. The only different it has with other status items (Volume, DateTime, Wi-Fi, BatteryIndicator, ...) is that if I select it and press left or right direction buttons on keyboard I can't navigate to other Items and like wise if I select another status item and press direction keys it will not select my status item and instead it jumps to another statusItem. I was wondering is there a way to fix this issue or is it standard for non OS statusItems?

Comment: None of the 3rd party apps I have on my status bar allows that either, so I'm guessing the arrow keys (along with other features such as command-drag) are only allowed by Apple default status bar apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu bar you see is not a uniform object. The application menu items on the left part belong to the current application. All these MenuItems are children to a common `NSMenu` object.

The status bar items on the outmost right belong to the system (Spotlight, Clock, TimeMachine etc.) and either also share a common parent `NSMenu` or just have some special privileges.

Each custom status bar menu item belongs to its corresponding application and has its own stand alone `NSMenu` parent object.
Each status menu is - as you know - inserted into a `NSStatusItem` which belongs to the `NSStatusBar` object. Both inherit directly from `NSObject` and (unlike `NSMenu`) lack interfaces to determine a status menu's parents or siblings. Each status bar item it absolutely isolated.

So, you can easily navigate with the arrow keys within a `NSMenu`, where every item knows its children and parents. Yet, it is not possible to navigate from your status bar menu to any other menu.